# Stuck in a loop while passing RequestBody in Postman

Tags: java, json

> 

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer implements Serializable{
    
    
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int custID;
    private String custName;
    @Id
    private String email;
    private int phone;
    
    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Transaction> transaction;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions")
public class Transaction implements Serializable{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int transID;
    private Date date;
    private int amount;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "custID", nullable= false)
    private Customer customer;
```

These are my entities, and I have a method:

```
@PostMapping("/record-transaction")
    public Transaction recordTransaction(@RequestBody Transaction transaction) {
        return transactionService.addTransaction(transaction);  
    }
```

But when I try to create JSON in postman, I get into a loop where while entering values for transaction, at the end I must enter the Customer object as well and when I am entering customer object at the end I again reach to enter the transaction's values. Its like a never ending loop. Help

I couldn't think of anything to do at all. My mind enters the loop itself.

Comment: Decouple your DB entities from your request by using an intermediate DTO.

Answer (score 0):

Decouple your DB entities from your request/response by using an intermediate DTO.

Controller:

```java
@PostMapping("/record-transaction")
public TransactionResponse recordTransaction(@RequestBody TransactionRequest body) {
     return TransactionResponse.from(transactionService.addTransaction(
         body.getDate();
         body.getAmount();
         body.getCustomerId();
     ));  
}
```

TransactionRequest:

```java
public class TransactionRequest {
    
    //don't need ID here it'll be auto generated in entity
    private Date date;
    private int amount;
    private int customerId;

}
```

TransactionResponse:

```java
public class TransactionResponse {
    
    private int id;
    private Date date;
    private int amount;
    private int customerId;

    public static TransactionResponse from(Transaction entity) {
        return //build response from entity here
    }

}
```

TransactionService:

```java
//when your entity is lean may as well pass the values directly to reduce boilerplate, otherwise use a DTO
public Transaction addTransaction(Date date, int amount, int customerId) {

    Customer customerRepo = customerRepo.findById(customerId).orElseThrow(
        () -> new CustomerNotFoundException();
    );

    Transaction trans = new Transaction();
    trans.setDate(date);
    trans.setAmount(amount);
    trans.setCustomer(customer);

    return transactionRepository.save(trans);
}
```

If you want to embed the customer model inside TransactionResponse or TransactionRequest it'll be fairly easy to do and this solution will produce way nicer contract and swagger docs than a bunch of use case specific annotations in your entity.

In general decoupling you request/response payloads, service dtos and entities from each other results in code with more boilerplate but easier to maintain and without weird unexpected side effects and specific logic.